# Attaching onclick on JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a problem since I wanted to attach the `onclick` alert function on an `<a/>` tag.
This thing doesn't work. The `alert('hi')` doesn't appear. Did I miss something?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        const requiredBy = true;
                if(requiredBy){
                    var banner = $(".bannerLink");
                    if(banner.length==0){
                        var pdpHead = $("[replaceclass='PDPHeadReplace']");
                        if(pdpHead.length!=0){
                            pdpHead.prepend('&lt;div class="bannerLink"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');
                            banner = pdpHead.find(".bannerLink");
                        }
                    }
                    if(banner.length!=0){
                        banner.append("&lt;a href='#' onclick='alert('hi')'&gt;&lt;img src='https://test.com' style='margin-top:5px;' &gt;&lt;/a&gt;");
                        $('.helloDiv').css({ 'display' : 'block', 'padding-top': '1rem'});
                    }
                }
    });
```

Comment: Since you use append, you dont need to use `&lt;`, you can just write it like normal html

Comment: Try with the third quote option, you can use `"` or `'` or ` ` `  try to nest with, ex.: `banner.append("&lt;a href='#' onclick='alert( \`hi\` )'&gt;&lt;img src='https://test.com' style='margin-top:5px;' &gt;&lt;/a&gt;");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick='alert(&quot;hi&quot;)'` for escaping `"`

Code:

```
banner.append("<a href='#' onclick='alert(&quot;hi&quot;)'><img src='https://test.com' style='margin-top:5px;' ></a>");
```

Edit: I changed `&lt;` and `&gt;` to `<` and `>` so that the element will not be appended as text

Comment: Already added but doesn't work still

Comment: It didn't work still

Comment: If you want to escape `'` the you can just do `onclick='alert(\'hi\')'`

Comment: Can you delete your answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

- First, you haven't skip the special characters to not `append` the `link` as `text` not `html`
- Second, you need to skip the nested `"` double quote inside the `alert`

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        const requiredBy = true;
                if(requiredBy){
                    var banner = $(".bannerLink");
                    if(banner.length==0){
                        var pdpHead = $("[replaceclass='PDPHeadReplace']");
                        if(pdpHead.length!=0){
                            pdpHead.prepend('&lt;div class="bannerLink"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');
                            banner = pdpHead.find(".bannerLink");
                        }
                    }
                    if(banner.length!=0){
                        banner.append("<a href='#' onclick='alert(\"hi\")'>link<img src='https://test.com' style='margin-top:5px;' </a>");
                        $('.helloDiv').css({ 'display' : 'block', 'padding-top': '1rem'});
                    }
                }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bannerLink"></div>
```

Comment: Weird. causes issue on my end

Comment: What is the issue has been caused?

Comment: It didn't appear

Comment: I'm not sure, what is the issue on your side, but it works on StackOverflow code snippet fine.

Comment: @Joseph What do you mean this is inside xml file ? If so please also post the XML file

Comment: Can you delete your answer?